# importing from parent directory, ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Tags: python

This has been asked before, but none of the solutions are yielding any results. I have a parent directory with

```
parent/
    __init__.py
    database.py
    collect/
        __init__.py
        collect.py
```

I would like to import `database.py` from `collect.py` but I constantly get `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`. Currently in `collect.py` I am just doing

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
import database
```

which does not feel very pythonic. I would like to have something like

```
from .. import database
```

Yet I always get that `ValueError`. Any help is appreciated. What exactly is causing this error. I thought adding `__init__.py` would fix the issue, but it changed nothing. Also, is there anything wrong with my current fix? It doesn't feel like the best solution to me.

Edit: I should add that I cannot successfully import from ipython running in `collect/` either, if that affects anything.

Comment: That is a fantastic explanation. Thanks. I see where the issue lies now. Is using `sys.path.append("..")` bad practice though? I will end up refactoring so I do not need it, but I am still curious.

Comment: I would not say it is bad practice but you have to be aware of what this means, i.e. "ultimately if all the possible directories do not contain a module of that name, have a look in the parent directory of this file". If a module named database was found before yours it would be loaded first.